# Google Maps Error ApiProjectMapError and SensorNotRequired

Tags: laravel, google-maps-api-3

in my laravel project i use this repo https://github.com/farhanwazir/laravelgooglemaps and i receive this error:

```
1. Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiProjectMapError
2. Google Maps JavaScript API warning: SensorNotRequired
```

in settings Sensor are false, and i have tried to change more API Key with and without protection but the result don't change.

with this error i can't see the map on my project

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using your own API key from your own project? If so, have you enabled all the APIs listed in the repo?

Comment: Are you using your own API key from your own project?
Yes, sure

If so, have you enabled all the APIs listed in the repo?
yes i have enabled all the APIs required in the repo

Comment: I see! Okay so can you try (1) re-enabling billing (assuming you have billing enabled - please double check you do) and (2) creating a new Cloud project (and then using a new API key from that new project)? Let me know if these solutions work please.